# Firebase non fatal feed

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Does anyone know if there is a way to export or get a feed of crashlytics non-fatal issues?  We want to create a process that would flag a new non-fatal issue or monitor the occurrences of existing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Firebase here. You could use the Big Query integration and Data Studio templates to push the data and run your own analysis. The data push would be once a day, but you could then use something like this:

```
SELECT issue_id 
FROM `cannonball-dogfood.crashlytics.io_fabric_samples_cannonball_ANDROID`
WHERE is_fatal=false 
AND application.build_version >= '1.1'  
LIMIT 10
```

(Cannonball is a sample app, so it would be for your app's table).